# Check if a filename is in a list

Tags: python-3.x, automation, filenames

I am trying to write a script that loops through all the files within a folder and compares it to a list. If a file name in that folder matches with an item in the list then I want to save a copy of that file in another folder.

I have tried this so far - my code runs but no files are saved in the new folder. Is anyone able to tell me why it's not working?

```
import os
import shutil
import fnmatch
import csv

sample = open(...../Sample.csv','r')
reader = csv.reader(sample)
samplelist= []

for row in reader:
    if row != " ":
     samplelist.append(row)


source = '..... /My Files'
destination = '.../Sample'

for file in os.listdir(directory):
    if file in samplelist:
       shutil.copy(source,destination)
```

Comment: I assume with the string `...../My Files` you are wanting to go up multiple directories? That syntax does not work. You need a `../` for every directory you want to go up. You need to do `../../../../My Files`

Comment: Hi that was just to demonstrate my directory but yes you are correct